# Copy HTTP request / response headers from a call to a HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I have a C# WCF service that receives a request Message and post it to another service.
Posting to the other service is done through HttpWebRequest.
How can i get in my service the original request HTTP headers and put them in the HttpWebRequest when i post them to the other service.

Something like this:

```
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProp = GetHttpRequestProp(requestMessage);
 HttpWebRequest loHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
  foreach (var item in httpRequestProp.Headers.AllKeys)
            {

                 loHttp.Headers.Add(item, httpRequestProp.Headers[item]);
            }
```

I know this doesn't work because HttpWebRequest loHttp has its own properties, and when i try to set ContentType for example in the above way it throws exception because it needs to be set like this:

```
loHttp.ContentType = httpRequestProp.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType];
```

So is there a way to copy the HTTP request headers from a call and put them as HTTP request headers to another HttpWebRequest ? Also the original request might have other custom headers set and i want send those also to the other service.

Thank you,
Adrya

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the headers via

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers
```

You can set the headers via

```
WebClient.Headers
```

Example:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("referer", "http://yourwebsite.com");
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

However, understand that some headers are restricted, and cannot be modified freely. These are:

- Accept
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Content-Type
- Date
- Expect
- Host
- If-Modified-Since
- Range
- Referer
- Transfer-Encoding
- User-Agent
- Proxy-Connection

I suppose you should look, case by case, which headers you can/want to replicate from the incoming call to the outgoing one.

Comment: I know how to get the headers, I don't know how to set them at the HttpWebRequest that i post to the other service...

Comment: As Roy said, some headers are protected and can only be set through the properties. So, the loop that you gave above is fine, except that you will have to have some special conditions where if for eg, the header name is Content-Length, you set the property instead of the request header directly

Comment: @Roy, please can you provide a source for the list of "restricted" headers you have listed - is it in an RFP?

Comment: Scratch that - I misunderstood - you mean protected in the sense they cannot be set in the headers collection.

Answer (score 2):

For ex. you want to copy all Request headers to the HttpWebRequest headers:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
CopyHeaders(httpWebRequest, httpWebRequest.Headers, this.Request.Headers);
```

and implementation:

```
    void CopyHeaders(object rootTo, NameValueCollection to, NameValueCollection from)
    {
        foreach (string header in from.AllKeys)
        {
            try
            {
                to.Add(header, from[header]);
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    rootTo.GetType().GetProperty(header.Replace("-", "")).SetValue(rootTo, from[header]);
                }
                catch {}
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.